# Indent c++ lambda with clang-format

Tags: c++, lambda, clang-format

Is there a way to indent c++11/14 lambda bodies with clang format? Also the closing brace should align with the `[]`

So I'd like it to look like this

```
auto l = []( int max ) -> std::vector<int> {
            std::vector<int> v( max );
            std::iota( v.begin(), v.end(), 0 );
            return v;
         };
```

instead of

```
auto l = []( int max ) -> std::vector<int> {
    std::vector<int> v( max );
    std::iota( v.begin(), v.end(), 0 );
    return v;
};
```