# clang-format: align lambda function parameter with continuation indent instead of opening brackets

Tags: c++, clang-format

This is a variable template used to verify string template arguments in a library I'm working on.

```cpp
template <fixed_string S>
inline constexpr bool verify_long_option = S.size() == 2 ||
  (std::find_if_not(S.begin(), S.end(), [](char c) {
                                             return ascii_isalnum(c) ||
                                               c == '-';
                                           }) == S.end());
```

`clang-format` seems to align the lambda to the edge of the bracket. What I want instead is this:

```
template <fixed_string S>
inline constexpr bool verify_long_option = S.size() == 2 ||
  (std::find_if_not(S.begin(), S.end(), [](char c) {
    return ascii_isalnum(c) || c == '-';
  }) == S.end());
```

I've tried setting `LambdaBodyIndentation: OuterScope`, but it doesn't seem to work here.

I have also tried removing the brackets, however, this results:

```cpp
template <fixed_string S>
inline constexpr bool verify_long_option =
  S.size() == 2 || std::find_if_not(S.begin(), S.end(), [](char c) {
                     return ascii_isalnum(c) || c == '-';
                   }) == S.end();
```

Is there an option that changes lambda alignment so that it lines up with the indent of the whole expression?

[This other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41170224/indent-c-lambda-with-clang-format) is related, but is the opposite of what I'm after.